# Will a magnet placed in between two current carrying wires move or not?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

If we place a  small magnet between two wires carrying current in opposite direction separated by some distance r, will the magnet move or not? And if the magnet will move then in what direction will it move and how?

Answer (score 2):

There will be a constructive magnetic field produced by both wires in the region between them. This field  will align the magnet such that the north pole points in the direction of the field and the south pole points in the direction opposite, like a compass aligned along the field line. This is because a magnetic field always tries to align the magnetic dipole moment vector with itself and the dipole moment of a magnet points wherever it's north pole points.